# Underscore isObject() sometimes not work

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

When I use nodeUnit to write unit tests for Backbone models, something weird happened, the question can be summarized as:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var player = new Player({name: 'Jacky'});
```

Then I update the player name with: player.set('name', 'Scott').
But I found that the name attribute is not updated at all(No validate function for this model), and there are weird attributes like: [0]: n, [1]: a, [2]: m, [3]: e.

It works fine if I changed the update method to player.set({name: 'Scott'}).

I did some quick investigation and found that Backbone.Model.set method depends on Underscore.isObject() method, and the latter is implemented as:

```
  _.isObject = function(obj) {
    return obj === Object(obj);
  };
```

I called the isObject() method in nodeUnit test cases, and in the first case it works fine, but in latter cases, it does not work as expected, for example isObject('name') will return true instead of the expected false.

Anyone have any idea what caused this?

Comment: Can you show us those latter test cases?

Comment: I can show you, but I'm afraid that it won't help:  
`var requirejs = require('requirejs');  
    requirejs.config({baseUrl: 'public/javascripts'});    
    requirejs(["app/cards", "app/rank"], function(Cards, Rank){    
        exports['Card equals'] = function(test){  
            test.ok(Cards.smallJoker().equals(Cards.smallJoker()));    
            test.done();   
        };
});`

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure that you are using the latest version of Backbone? Backbone in older versions didn't support shortcut version for the `set` method (`.set(key, value)`) and allowed only object with attribute/value pairs as a parameter.

*(i believe it was added in 0.9)*

Comment: Actually yes, I'm using backbone version **0.9.2**

Comment: It would also happen if the `name` was a string created using the `new String('name')` - awkward but this is the only way `_.isObject` would return `true` with a `string` does it happen in browser or nodejs/headless env?

Comment: Thanks Tom Tu. but I'm not using anything like new String("").